# centOS: error: Socket.pm is older than 2.006

Tags: centos

Yesterday I installed centOS in my vmware to run rancid.
According to [this site](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch1_:_Network_Backups_With_Rancid#.WMa-qjuLTtR):

I did step by step but when I came to command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/rancid/
```

the error was found:

> **checking Socket.pm version... Socket version 2.006 required--this is only version 1.78 at -e line 1. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   -e line 1. configure: error: Socket.pm is older than 2.006; upgrade from http://metacpan.org/pod/Socket**

so i can not continue, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call

```
cpanm Socket
```

from your shell. This will install the latest version of Socket